# slideToggle a div by finding the div using custom variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to select a div (such as the one with compid 80) in javascript/jquery and then slideToggle the content div within it? I know it's possible using the .next(). However i need the slideToggle to be called from another piece of code from within a google map infowindow.

Basically is there a way to grab the div with compid80 and somehow call:

```
$(div with compid80).next().slideToggle('slow')
```

Currently i use (and it works fine but i need this function to be called manually when another event occurs)

```
$(document).delegate(".heading",'click',function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});

<div class="heading" compid="80" usedspec="33"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
<div class="heading" compid="81" usedspec="34"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
<div class="heading" compid="82" usedspec="35"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
<div class="heading" compid="83" usedspec="36"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
<div class="heading" compid="84" usedspec="37"><div class="content">content in here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using:        $('div[compid="' + compid + '"]').next().slideToggle('slow');

Comment: Next() won't get you the child element. This could work if you replace next() with children() or find().

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nCHbK/

```
$('.heading').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('compid') == '80') {
        $(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
    }
});
```